# Ext JS GridPanel height gets set to 0 when adding new elements to the website

Tags: javascript, php, css, extjs, gridpanel

I am using Ext JS 3.4 to display some data in grids and I have differences between localhost and server version.
Some GridPanels in my website got their height set to 0 after I added new buttons in a different panel. The issue only shows up on the server and I am unable to replicate in on my localhost.
The first picture shows the correct way the grid is displayed without the new elements, and the second shows the bugged display with the elements.

[Correct display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92oJm.png)

[Bugged display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24Cei.png)

The code for the GridPanel is the following:

```
 var timeStampGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    border       : false,
    stripeRows   : true,
    store        : timestampJsonStore,
    colModel     : colTimestampModel,
    tbar         : timestampToolbar,
    loadMask     : true,
    autoExpandColumn : 'timeValue',
    bbar         : pagingToolbar,
    selModel : new Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel({
        listeners : {
            'rowselect' : function(model, index) {
                currentRow = index;
            }
        }
    })
});
```

The code for the new buttons:

```
/*** delete top banner ***/
var delete_top_banner_Btn = new Ext.Button({
    text : Lang.translate('DELETE_TOP_BANNER'),
    icon : 'js/images/delete.png',
    handler : onTopBannerDelete
});
 /*** delete buttom banner ***/
var delete_buttom_banner_Btn = new Ext.Button({
    text : Lang.translate('DELETE_BUTTOM_BANNER'),
    icon : 'js/images/delete.png',
    handler : onButtomBannerDelete
});
```

What I have tried:

1. Removing the new buttons => correct display
2. Add different types of new elements (labels, grids) => bugged display
3. Set the height and width of the GridPanel manually => bugged display
4. Different browsers => bugged display
5. Removing the GripPanel => bug appeared on an adjacent grid
6. Move the new buttons to different locations of website => bugged display

Since the bug appears only on the server I tried to think about the differences between the server and localhost:

- Server: virtual LEMP - Nginx(1.4.6)+PHP(5.5.9)+MySQL
- Localhost: windows 10 xampp + PHP(5.6.15)
- Also the Ext JS version on both server and localhost (same files) is 3.4

Although I don't see how the php version might affect the JavaScript Ext JS I did try changing the php version on my localhost in an attempt to replicate the bug on localhost with no success.

I have tried to search within known issues of Ext Js 3.4 but none seemed to be relevant. Also within other questions on the website only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730688/ext-js-gridpanel-autoheight-not-working-for-group-expand-collapse) seems similar.

Comment: Check the containers and the layout configs that you are using. Is the page too complex?

Comment: Hi! I've checked the containers of the all the elements involved. They all seem to be used as per documentation. The issue still persists server side and I was unable to recreate it on localhost.
I would say the page is quite complex but I do not have the time for a serious refactoring.
Thank you for your comment.